# How to create an "ALL" variable for SUMIFS function

Tags: excel, sumifs

So I am working on a personal little project to be able to analyze baseball hitting and pitching data pulled from Baseball-Reference based off of 6 variables. I currently have named ranges in dropdown lists that I'm using in combination with a `SUMIFS` function to pull in the data from other sheets. However the issue I'm having is that I cannot figure out a way to create an "All" variable.

For example, one of my variables is the month a game took place. At the moment I cannot figure a way too look at a game from every month, only a specific month.

I've placed a [screenshot of the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9O2B.png) I'm currently using, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put asterisk symbol (*) in the Months criteria (cell B3), it works as a wildcard[image].

Only limitation is, that it won't count the rows where the Month is empty.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking to do. Luckily there aren't any blank rows so this solves my issue perfectly!